# he charged the gunman

Tags: meaning

Example:

> Army vet Chris Mintz **charged the gunman** after pulling alarms and telling students to run.

What does it exactly mean when you are charging someone as used in the example sentence above? Typically when you charge someone, it means that you are demanding that they pay you money for the service you have provided them with. Another common meaning of the verb *charge* is when you rush forward in attack or engage someone in combat, but, when used like that, there is usually a preposition coming after the verb *charge*. For example:

> The plan is to charge headlong at the enemy.

Comment: See http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charge, transitive verb definition 4b.

Comment: You don't ***pull** alarms*. You do things like ***ring, sound, trigger, activate** alarms*. So whereas *charging the gunman* is perfectly normal English, I have my doubts the writer is a normal native speaker. Unless this incident took place in a train, where you might still have to pull an alarm *chain*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In the US we not only "pull" alarms colloquially, we are instructed to do so by the manufacturer. Take a look at [this](http://blacksportsonline.com/home/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/fire-alarm-.jpg).

Comment: I just looked it up in [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/charge). Your example, "The plan is to charge headlong at the enemy", is definition 5 ([no object] Rush forward in attack). Just below it is definition 5.1, which fits your text: 5.1: [with object] Rush aggressively towards (someone or something) in attack: *I don’t advise anyone to charge that barricade*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, in this context, it has the second meaning; to rush at the gunman. For a similar preposition-less example, see verse 4 of Tennyson's "[The Charge of the Light Brigade](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/174586)"

As others have said, "after pulling alarms" is stilted. I'd have written "after raising the alarm".